# Using jQuery inArray and hiding an option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to be able to hide certain option values within my loop. At the moment the whole option select values get hidden. How can I make it work?

```
function initialStrandOptions() {
 if($('#component_id_1').prop('checked') == true){
  var strand_options = $('.strand_options').find('option')
   strand_options.each(function(){
    if(jQuery.inArray(strand_options, ['4', '5', '6', '7'])){
     $(this).hide();
    }
   });  
 }
}
```

Is there a better way also of achieving my goal?

Comment: So you want to hide options that are in array?

Comment: yes, that’s what I am trying to achieve.Hide options 4,5,6 and 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check value of the currently iterated option referenced by `this` in the loop, and also compare it with `-1` returned by [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
function initialStrandOptions() {
    if ($('#component_id_1').prop('checked') == true) {
        var strand_options = $('.strand_options').find('option')
        strand_options.each(function () {
            if (jQuery.inArray(this.value, ['4', '5', '6', '7']) > -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkv3szpz/1/)**

Comment: thank you, didn’t realise I had to compare against -1 as I thought -1 was returned if not found

Comment: Yes, `-1` means "not found". This is what you need: hide options that are **not** `-1` (meaning, found in array). So you can either use `> -1` or `!= -1`.

Comment: ah ok thank you, that helps. so could i do something like `this.value, != 1` and compare against -1

Comment: @Richlewis Yes, you can check with `!=-1`